# AngularFire2 - Using RXJS Observable.groupBy

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

I am having a hard time trying to use groupBy with angularfire2 (currently 5.0.0-rc.3)

I have the following function:

```
   get(): Observable<any> {
    return this.af
        .list(this.path, ref => ref.limitToLast(100))
        .valueChanges()
        .map(list => {
            return list.map( (item:any) => {
              //Do some stuff
              return item;
            })
            //Chaining groupBy here won't work
            ;
        })
        //Chaining groupBy here does nothing (subscribe will not fire)
        .subscribe(data => { 
           //Do other stuff 
        });
  }
```

I need to group this list on certain attribute, I could not make it work following RXJS doc

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html

Any help is appreciated.